# Allow other php scripts to be executed besides index.php using Symfony 4 and nginx

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, nginx-location

I guess I don't understand the syntax well enough to understand why I can't achieve this.

Given the following folder structure

```
- www/website
-- public
--- index.php
--- otherscript.php
```

And the following nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen          8000;
    server_name     localhost;
    root            /www/website/public;
    index           index.php;

    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed) 
    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # would always refer to index.php (server directive)
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ## tried this - no dice
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        index $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Every request I make is being redirected to index.php, Which makes sense.
I want to be able to execute localhost:8000/otherscript.php without being redirected to index.php.

How can I do this without breaking symfony's routing?

Comment: You could change `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$)` to `location ~ \.php(/|$)` and remove the `internal` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith Still no dice, every other script aside from index.php is being ignored :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `/index.php` handler you need to include `fastcgi_params` file, so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

Be sure to place this *after* `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {` because regex locations are matched in order of presence in configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, and here I was thinking I tried that already :/ Well surprise surprise, I was digging way too far for a solution. Thanks buddy

Comment: Danila, your approach worked, but can you explain this:
Browsing to `localhost:8000/otherscript.php` executes the script, browsing to `localhost:8000` downloads index.php instead of executing it

Comment: @DerpyNerd perhaps you did not put the block `location ~ \.php$ {` the lowest in the configuration. You can try changing the initial config in a way that it will match on only specific scripts. After all, it is most secure to list the scripts allowed for execution rather than blindly allowing all to run, so try replacing `location ~ \.php$ {` with `location ~ ^/(otherscript|foo)\.php(/|$) {` to allow only `otherscript.php` and `foo.php` to run aside from `index.php`. It won't matter then where it is placed within the config (before or after index handler).

Comment: it is definitely placed last in the server block. I'll give specifying scripts by name a shot